# To Rails from Django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

Historically, I'm a django developer. I find myself suddenly in a position where I'll be doing a bunch of rails programming. I've browsed through the rails docs and done a bit of poking and prodding. Most assume that I've never seen a web framework or (worse) that I've never written code.

Ideally I'd like a resources that is targeted towards people who know django (pylons / sinatra / etc would be fine) and tells me the differences that I need to know to get on my feet with ruby.

Such things are incredibly hard to search for, because the web is littered with "django vs rails" articles.

Is there a good rails resource that assumes knowledge of other frameworks? What do I need to know, going from django to ruby?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm in the same position as you: I need to learn Rails for work, and I was hoping to find an article/tutorial that expresses Rails concepts in terms of **how they differ from Django concepts**.

After a lot of searching, I found this:

### http://www.vaporbase.com/rails-django

This compares the ways in which Rails and Django each implement various web development concepts.

It's very long and in-depth, but it's well structured so you can just dip into the bits you need help understanding.

One big downside, though: it was written in 2007. But it's still useful as long as you bare this in mind.

---

**UPDATE**:

I've also found this – a shorter, more up-to-date, cheatsheet-style comparison:

### [Rails Quick Start for Djangonauts](http://blog.jupo.org/2011/07/30/rails-quick-start-for-djangonauts/)

This one is good for quickly checking what terminology is used by each framework for a given concept.

Comment: Sadly, the first link you posted has gone missing, here's an archive.org link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120202114257/http://www.vaporbase.com:80/rails-django

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the answer here is "No".

Maybe I'll write one.